# formatting using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a function that returns the month and day. I want that if day/month is less than 10 then it should append 0 before it and should return 01 instead of 1. how can I do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
return DateTime.Now.ToString("dd"); //day
return DateTime.Now.ToString("MM"); //month
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of [formatting options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for dates and times, including [specifying your own](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).  How you'd use them depends a lot on how your code is creating and returning a "month and day."

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2011, 3, 4, 16, 5, 7, 123);
String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", dt);          // "03/04/2011"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom format when you turn the number into a string:

```
string dayFormatted = day.ToString("00");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not altogether clear what the exact format you want, but if you want the format to be like this:

```
dd/mm
```

where both `dd` and `mm` is formatted with two digits, then [string.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) will do that for you:

```
string.Format("{0:00}/{1:00}", day, month); // 20/03 for today
```

Of course, if you really have a DateTime, you can do it directly:

```
string.Format("{0:dd/MM}", DateTime.Now);   // 20/03 for today (*)
```

- (*) note that when using DateTime formatting, / will be replaced with the cultural character for separating parts of a date, so in some cases it might be a dot, not a slash